# the first call of QPainter::drawText() takes very long causing flicker

Tags: qt

I have a problem with flickering at application startup. I reduced this problem to this very simple code snippet.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QElapsedTimer>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QWidget>

class Widget : public QWidget {
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) {
        QPainter p(this);
        QElapsedTimer t;
        t.start();
        p.drawText(20, 20, "XYZ");
        qDebug() << "drawing text takes" << t.elapsed() << "ms";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QElapsedTimer t;
    t.start();
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget widget;
    widget.show();
    a.processEvents();
    qDebug() << "starting application takes" << t.elapsed() << "ms";
    return a.exec();
}
```

It shows a white window for almost a second and then it draws a text. The log says "drawing text takes 950 ms" when it is drawn for the first time. This is in release mode. Subsequent draws are almost immediate, something like 0 ms. Is there anything I can do to make this faster so that the window does not flicker?

I assume the first call prepares some data (probably font related) which are then cached for the subsequent calls. Can I do something to prepare these data and cache these even before the first draw?

For example, if I wrote this: `QLabel lbl("XYZ"); lbl.show();` instead of my own widget, it will not flicker. Any ideas how they avoided flickering in `QLabel`?

I am on Windows 10 with Qt 5.11.1.

Comment: In linux with Qt 5.11.1 delay between 30 to 40 ms.

Comment: @eyllanesc I updated the code and added a timer into `main()`. Can you run the updated code to measure the total startup time on Linux? My typical application start up timing says 1020 ms total time, of which 950 ms is the text drawing.

Comment: Have you deployed it in release mode?

Comment: new code: `starting application takes 140 ms
drawing text takes 34 ms`

Comment: Yes, it is release mode.

Comment: Have you executed it several times or only once?

Comment: Several times. The measured times vary, of course. I wrote here the typical medium values. Sometimes it is 600 ms, sometimes it is 1200 ms.

Comment: try with QStyle: https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Change_the_Background_Color_of_QWidget

Comment: No change with `QStyle`.

Comment: Have you tried on other machines?

Comment: Yes, all running Windows 10. The same problem.

Comment: Then report it as a bug. Your code is simple, it should work, so the problem seems to be Qt.

Comment: Use [QStaticText](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstatictext.html) to improve performance.

Comment: It is already reported one year ago. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45485492/performance-issues-when-painting-text-on-custom-item-delegates-in-qt-c) is the question on SO and [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-62309) the bug report. Please add a comment there in order to increase the chance to fix it.