# QStyledItemDelegate::paint - Why do the passed QStyleOptionViewItem have a rect property of size 0x0?

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview, qstyleditemdelegate

I have a `QListView` where I set the model to a custom `QAbstractItemModel`, as well as a custom `QStyledItemDelegate`.

```cpp
ui->listView->setModel(model);
ui->listView->setItemDelegate(new Delegate(ui->listView));
```

I followed [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53110350/2546414) on how to set the delegate up properly, so I overloaded `paint()` and `sizeHint()`:

```cpp
void
Delegate::paint(QPainter *painter,
                const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    std::cout << __func__ << ": " << option.rect.width() << "x" << option.rect.height() << std::endl;

    QStyleOptionViewItem opt(option);
    initStyleOption(&opt, index);

    painter->save();
    // draw background of option.rect and some text
    painter->restore();
}
```

```cpp
QSize
Delegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                   const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    std::cout << __func__ << ": " << option.rect.width() << "x" << option.rect.height() << std::endl;

    return QSize(option.rect.width(), 100);
}
```

When I add an item to my model, it is properly propagated to the `QListView` and the delegate prints the following:

```
sizeHint: 1551x87
sizeHint: 0x0
paint: 0x0
```

Every new item I add is then drawn on top of the previous items, and the backgrounds aren't drawn, since `option.rect` is `0x0`.

I've tried changing a bunch of its size-related properties of my `QListView` to no avail.

So why do the passed `QStyleOptionViewItem` have a `rect` of `0x0`, or generally, where do the `QStyleOptionViewItem` get its properties from? Qt's [`paint` documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#paint) and [`sizeHint` documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#sizeHint) doesn't seem very clear on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sizeHint() is there so that you tell the size you need, option.rect will then get this value for the painting / resizing of the cell

Comment: @chehrlic I've set `sizeHint` to return `QSize(option.rect.width(), 100)`, so shouldn't the height in `paint` at least be 100?

Comment: I have not read Qt's code for that part but if your `QSize` is not valid (`width == 0` => `isValid() == false`), I am not surprised you are getting this behavior.

Comment: Returning hardcoded `QSize(100, 100)` in `sizeHint` does not change the behaviour (ie `paint` does not receive `option.rect` of size `100x100`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was found in the model instead (`columnCount()` being calculated wrong). So if you encounter the same issue, try checking the model implementation.

By using the default `QListView` delegate, nothing was printed, even though I use `Qt::DisplayRole`. This way, the issue was isolated to be in the model, and not the view nor the delegate.