# QTableView performance

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm using a `QTableView` with PyQt5. As soon as I start to display a few thousand rows, the performance is abysmal. I tried the suggestions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691577/qtableview-slow-performance-with-1000s-of-visible-cells) but the Qt Graphics View framework and `QTreeView` are not viable options for me. Does anybody have other ideas for optimizing the performance of a `QTableView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mirror the effect of `QTreeView`'s `setUniformRowHeights` by implementing `sizeHintForRow`:

```
class UniformRowHeights(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._row_height = None
    def sizeHintForRow(self, row):
        model = self.model()
        if row < 0 or row >= model.rowCount():
            # Mirror super implementation.
            return -1
        return self.get_row_height()
    def get_row_height(self):
        if self._row_height is None:
            self._row_height = max(self._get_cell_heights())
        return self._row_height
    def changeEvent(self, event):
        # This for instance happens when the style sheet changed. It may affect
        # the calculated row height. So invalidate:
        self._row_height = None
        super().changeEvent(event)
    def _get_cell_heights(self, row=0):
        self.ensurePolished()
        option = self.viewOptions()
        model = self.model()
        for column in range(model.columnCount()):
            index = model.index(row, column)
            delegate = self.itemDelegate(index)
            if delegate:
                yield delegate.sizeHint(option, index).height()
```